# Finding $E(X^2)$ of a random variable $X$~$exp(λ)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function

$X$ has the probability density function $f(x)=\frac{1}λe^{-x/λ}$.

The expected value of $X^2$ should be (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)) equal to $n!/λ^n$ , namely $2/λ^2$. This should be derived from the integral $E(X^2)=\int x^2f(x)dx$, with the limits ranging from $0$ to $∞ $.

I've tried integrating by parts but I still cannot derive the correct answer, am I forgetting something? Thankful for any aid or hints!

Edit: I'll update with my integration by parts (twice).

$E(X^2)=\int x^2f(x) dx= [-x^2e^{-x/λ}]-\int -2xe^{-x/λ} = [-x^2e^{-x/λ}]+2\int xe^{-x/λ}=$

$=[-x^2e^{-x/λ}]+2([-x\frac{1}λe^{-x/λ}]+\int\frac{1}λe^{-x/λ}) =[-x^2e^{-x/λ}] +2[-x\frac{1}λe^{-x/λ}] + 2[-e^{-x/λ}] =$

$= 0+0+2(0+1/e^0)=2$

Comment: Integrating by parts twice seems the way to go. Maybe post your attempt so we can try to see where it's going wrong

Comment: Actually, integrating by parts twice is more work than showing the general formula using induction. In that case you only have to use partial integration once.

Comment: There is a probable typo, I think $e^{-x/\lambda}$ may be intended.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, thank you!

Comment: @StellaBiderman I did in fact integrate by parts twice, and didn't get the correct answer. I'll edit in my method but might take a while, still new to the formatting on the site.

Comment: As written down, the function is not a density function on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I corrected the typo, does your comment still apply? If so, the interval was my own assumption and nothing stated in the text. If that's the wrong, I'd be happy to know!

Comment: The corrected version is a density on $(0,\infty)$, and a couple of integrations by parts will do it. I wish they would not use the letter $\lambda$, since it is likely to lead to confusion. The Wikipedia entry probably involves the density function $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$.  Also exponential distribution, different choice of parameter.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I believe you are right, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^2\dfrac{1}{\lambda}e^{-x/\lambda}\text{ d}x = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-x/\lambda}\text{ d}x\text{.}$$
[There is a useful result that can come into play here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110193/reducing-int-0-infty-xn-e-ax-mathrmdx): namely, for $a > 0$
and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-ax}\text{ d}x = \dfrac{n!}{a^{n+1}}$$

hence
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-x/\lambda}\text{ d}x = \dfrac{2!}{(1/\lambda)^{3}} = 2\lambda^3\text{.}$$
So, the expected value in this case is $\dfrac{2\lambda^3}{\lambda} = 2\lambda^2$.

I think your PDF is wrong: it should probably be $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, $\lambda, x > 0$.

If this were the case,
$$\mathbb{E}[X^{2}] = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^2\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\text{ d}x = \lambda \int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\lambda x}\text{ d}x = \lambda\left(\dfrac{2!}{\lambda^3}\right) = \dfrac{2}{\lambda^2}\text{.}$$

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the correct answer, as an earlier comment pointed out the function I have would not yield $2/λ^{2}$. So you are most likely correct. Your last comment, do you mean that the function $λe^{-λx}$ would be the only way of getting it in the form wikipedia wrote?

Comment: @Newman See my edit.